# Jenkins slave on Windows XP not starting

Tags: jenkins, windows-xp-sp3

I had this all working, what changed I am baffled.

I have a Jenkins slave running on XP and when I go to start launch the slave, I get

> Checking if Java exists
>   No Java found. Downloading JDK
>   Installing JDK
>   ERROR: Failed to prepare Java
>   jcifs.smb.SmbException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:545)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:646)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:244)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:770)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.mkdir(SmbFile.java:2518)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.mkdirs(SmbFile.java:2544)
>       at hudson.os.windows.WindowsRemoteFileSystem.mkdirs(WindowsRemoteFileSystem.java:58)
>       at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:250)
>       at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:204)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

At the XP machine console, I have

> C:\Documents and Settings\build>java -version
>   java version "1.7.0_09"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this finally by creating an account at Oracle and downloading the JRE from there, jenkins did the downloading and alas, it all works now.